# Make a directory folder hidden or unreachable

Tags: php

This is my problem, I have a index.php which is my login form. I will explain my problem so it should not be complicated to understand.

I have a main folder inside it is I have a folder named templates and index.php so this is what it would look like

Main Folder

- class(folder)
- templates(folder)

  - home.php
- index.php

How can I make the templates folder unreachable so when any user types www.anysite.com/mainfolder/templates, the user can't see my templates folder or user cannot see my directory, or the user will be redirected to my Error Site.

Comment: use htaccess redirect methode

Comment: set permission to file/folder

Comment: Have you tried to look for a solution? As @nickle said, you could use htaccess for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in htaccess

```
<Files *>
 Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named `.htaccess` in the folder with this content:

```
deny from all
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file and paste `Redirect /mainfolder/ error-folder/403.php`